# How to direct-initialize a derived class with an abstract base?

Tags: c++, c++20

Without the virtual method, the `make_unique` line in `main` compiles ok. But I'm lost as to how to direct-initialize a `Derived` like this when it's there. Is this possible?

```cpp
struct Base
{
    virtual void method();
};
struct Derived : public Base
{
    int i;
};

int main() {
    Base base{}; // this works
    make_unique<Derived>(Base{}, 3); // this doesn't compile unless the virtual method is removed
}
```

I don't see any mention of virtual methods in the "Direct initilization" page: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization

Comment: maybe it's because it's an Aggregate? I see "no virtual member functions" on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Comment: Yes, with the `virtual` method, your `Derived` class is not an aggregate anymore, so this form of initialization can't be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the `virtual` method, your `Derived` class is not an aggregate anymore, so this form of initialization can't be done.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

An aggregate is one of the following types:

- array type
- class type (typically, `struct` or `union`), that has

  - no user-declared constructors
    (until C++11)
  - no user-provided, inherited, or explicit constructors
    (since C++11)
    (until C++20)
  - no user-declared or inherited constructors
    (since C++20)
  - no private or protected [direct (since C++17)] non-static data members
  - no base classes
    (until C++17)
  - no virtual base classes (since C++17)
  - no private or protected direct base classes
    (since C++17)
  - **no virtual member functions**
  - no default member initializers
    (since C++11)
    (until C++14)

Comment: seems like a weird restriction tbh

Comment: @Spongman Sometimes some restrictions may seem artificial but they are usually there to cover some cornercases. It wasn't until C++17 aggregates could have base classes at all.

Comment: There is weird-and-implementation-specific stuff going on with `virtual` methods that the Standardization body probably doesn't want to wreck.